# Bootstrap 5 tabs display as tab panels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 to create a layout that when >= 992 pixels in width it displays a table in the sidebar and some text in the main content area. If the browser is resized to < 992 pixels, the sidebar disappears and the table and text are both displayed in the main content area as tabbed panels. Here is the code:

```
 <main class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <aside class="d-none d-lg-block col-lg-4">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">My Car</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Year</td>
                            <td>2023</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Make</td>
                            <td>Honda</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Model</td>
                            <td>Civic</td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </aside>
            <div class="col ps-md-4">
                <div class="d-lg-none">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mt-5">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#table" data-bs-toggle="tab">Table</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#text" data-bs-toggle="tab">Text</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="d-lg-none tab-pane fade show active tab-container" id="table">
                        <!-- This is duplicate content from sidebar -->
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="2">My Car</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Year</td>
                                    <td>2023</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Make</td>
                                    <td>Honda</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Model</td>
                                    <td>Civic</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show tab-container" id="text">
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vel massa laoreet, tristique est eget, pulvinar lacus. Nam nec diam at diam elementum porttitor ac ac sapien. Quisque ut consectetur magna. Suspendisse vestibulum magna mollis, elementum justo at, aliquet lorem. Etiam auctor nisi vitae efficitur sagittis. Morbi dui sem, consectetur vel fermentum sit amet, sollicitudin eget lectus. Mauris malesuada faucibus diam, in condimentum risus lacinia finibus. Aliquam porta ornare lacus, a blandit dolor interdum vel. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

This layout is displaying as intended when <992px wide, but when >= 992px, the text displays in the main content area only if that tab was selected. It seems to have to do with the `.active` class that Bootstrap adds/removes as tabs are selected/deselected. Not sure how to fix this?

Link to [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Pixel-Paul/pen/bGQYzqo)

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap tabs are designed to not be displayed until selected (active).

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane {
    display: none;
}
```

You can get around this by adding the `d-lg-block` class to the `#text` `div`.

```
<div class="d-lg-block tab-pane fade show tab-container" id="text">
```

However, in the scenario (such as a "desktop" browser window that isn't maximized) when the user switches between tabs in a narrow viewport and then widens the viewport, the issue would come again due to the JS removing the `show` class.

```
.fade:not(.show) {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <main class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <aside class="d-none d-lg-block col-lg-4 border">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">My Car</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Year</td>
                            <td>2023</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Make</td>
                            <td>Honda</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Model</td>
                            <td>Civic</td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </aside>
            <div class="col ps-md-4 border">
                <div class="d-lg-none">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mt-5">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#table" data-bs-toggle="tab">Table</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#text" data-bs-toggle="tab">Text</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="d-lg-none tab-pane fade show active tab-container" id="table">
                        <!-- This is duplicate content from sidebar -->
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="2">My Car</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Year</td>
                                    <td>2023</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Make</td>
                                    <td>Honda</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Model</td>
                                    <td>Civic</td>
                                </tr>
                                
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show tab-container d-lg-block" id="text">
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vel massa laoreet, tristique est eget, pulvinar lacus. Nam nec diam at diam elementum porttitor ac ac sapien. Quisque ut consectetur magna. Suspendisse vestibulum magna mollis, elementum justo at, aliquet lorem. Etiam auctor nisi vitae efficitur sagittis. Morbi dui sem, consectetur vel fermentum sit amet, sollicitudin eget lectus. Mauris malesuada faucibus diam, in condimentum risus lacinia finibus. Aliquam porta ornare lacus, a blandit dolor interdum vel. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

I don't like duplicating the content but don't want to invest time into redesigning your layout. Since you're already duplicating the table, the easiest fix is to also duplicate the text.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <main class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <aside class="d-none d-lg-block col-lg-4 border">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2">My Car</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Year</td>
                            <td>2023</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Make</td>
                            <td>Honda</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Model</td>
                            <td>Civic</td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </aside>
            <div class="col ps-md-4 border">
              <div class="d-none d-lg-block">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vel massa laoreet, tristique est eget, pulvinar lacus. Nam nec diam at diam elementum porttitor ac ac sapien. Quisque ut consectetur magna. Suspendisse vestibulum magna mollis, elementum justo at, aliquet lorem. Etiam auctor nisi vitae efficitur sagittis. Morbi dui sem, consectetur vel fermentum sit amet, sollicitudin eget lectus. Mauris malesuada faucibus diam, in condimentum risus lacinia finibus. Aliquam porta ornare lacus, a blandit dolor interdum vel. </p>
              </div>
                <div class="d-lg-none">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mt-5">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#table" data-bs-toggle="tab">Table</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#text" data-bs-toggle="tab">Text</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="d-lg-none tab-pane fade show active tab-container" id="table">
                        <!-- This is duplicate content from sidebar -->
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="2">My Car</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Year</td>
                                    <td>2023</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Make</td>
                                    <td>Honda</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Model</td>
                                    <td>Civic</td>
                                </tr>
                                
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show tab-container" id="text">
                       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vel massa laoreet, tristique est eget, pulvinar lacus. Nam nec diam at diam elementum porttitor ac ac sapien. Quisque ut consectetur magna. Suspendisse vestibulum magna mollis, elementum justo at, aliquet lorem. Etiam auctor nisi vitae efficitur sagittis. Morbi dui sem, consectetur vel fermentum sit amet, sollicitudin eget lectus. Mauris malesuada faucibus diam, in condimentum risus lacinia finibus. Aliquam porta ornare lacus, a blandit dolor interdum vel. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: I  was hoping to avoid duplicating the text content (and the table content). Maybe I need to rethink my layout.